# How do I use firebase google sign in, server side on replit

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am coding a firebase sign in and hosting it on replit but each time I try to sign in wtih google I get this errror {"code":"auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment","customData":{},"name":"FirebaseError"}. I have sign in with google active in my firebase authentication dashboard, also signing in with email and password works. Please help.

If you want to check out my code the github link is here https://github.com/ObviousTeam/firebase-auth

Also my github page is here https://replit.com/@ozabramo/take-6#accountmanagement/login.js